# iPad mini 3 bought from United States

Tags: ipad

I bought a brand new iPad mini 3 64GB from a auction site, I knew it was imported from the US, that's fine, I'm now unsure as to what SIM card I can use in it, it won't accept an O2 SIM card.

Can I use it in the UK on cellular, if so what network SIM card might I have to get.

Comment: If ti wont accept another SIM card, then it is locked to the previous Telephone provider.

Comment: You will also need to check what carriers the device supports, as 3G/4G in different countries can sometimes utilize different frequencies for their networks.

Answer (score 1):

No iPads have ever been network locked and all current model iPads with cellular connectivity support both CDMA and GSM networks (see [Apple's LTE information](http://www.apple.com/ipad/LTE/)), with no frequency limitations.

What that means is that your US-purchased iPad Mini *should* work just fine with an O2 data SIM (and any other UK data SIM for that matter - EE, Vodafone or Three). If your SIM isn't working, I'd verify:

- Is it a data SIM?
- Does the SIM work in other devices (eg, try in a cellular dongle)